# Is there a way to access xml of forms/workflows via suitescript 2.0 in NetSuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

[Form XML from UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yxJvN.png)

Basically these are available via SDF and I wanted to understand if these can be accessed SERVER-SIDE via SuiteScript

Answer (score 0):

By adding the following parameter to the record URL `&xml=t`, you can see the record's XML.

If you want to see it Server-Side you need to make a GET request to that URL.

PS: in some records, you need to remove the edit parameter ( `e=t` ) before

Comment: I'm not trying to access record's XML. I'm looking for ways to access form/workflow XML, tried using https.get call with TBA and it did not work.